# wireless does not work in Astra Linux current - Debian variant. Have bpo kernel

Tags: debian, wifi, backports

I had earlier got help here [fresh linux mint 18.1 install - no wireless, though the live cd it worked fine in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350137/fresh-linux-mint-18-1-install-no-wireless-though-the-live-cd-it-worked-fine-i) but I needed to move from "stable" to "current", in the debian variant Astra Linux common.

I've tried doing the same thing as in the prior post, but things are a little different. I had the kernel 4.8.0-? but then I read on here somewhere to try a jessie-backport kernel. So I added it to the source list and found 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64.

I rebooted and the mouse now works!

So then I moved on to fix the wifi. Already had dkms and wireless-tools. So I downloaded broadcom

```
~$ sudo aptitude -t jessie-backports search broadcom- 
i   broadcom-sta-dkms          - dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver                                                                                   
v   broadcom-sta-modules       -                                                                                                     

sudo dpkg -i broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-5~bpo8+1_all.deb
```

but the install fails because of no headers... so I look for them (in jessie-backports) but there is a failure without any resolution;

```
sbh@sbh:~/Downloads$ sudo aptitude -t jessie-backports install linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0{a} linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86{ab} linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-common{a} linux-kbuild-4.9{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.3 MB of archives. After unpacking 59.3 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 : Depends: gcc-4.9 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 [Not Installed]         
2)     linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 [Not Installed]  



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 [Not Installed]         
2)     linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 [Not Installed]  
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

So I think I want to install it.... but I already have gcc-6, gcc-6-base, and I suppose most, if not all, of it.

I did try installing the compiler in the solution as well but it complained of no gcc-4.9. I then tried to install it but it complained it was not available - maybe it is on a wheezy backport (I just thought...)

PS. I just looked on the browser instead of searching on the CL and noticed, https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 that there are dependencies for the linux-headers: ...compiler..., ...common...., and ...kbuild... But I see that the compiler depends on gcc-4.9. Still Why won't it compile under gcc-6?

**UPDATE**

I had already chased about 90% of the dependencies down in packages.debian.org/jessie-backports and installed them via `dpkg -i`, including the last broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-5~bpo8+1_all.deb, in order. But I went ahead with @GADR3 advice and ran the modprobe commands and now it works!

I will try to move out of a bpo kernel, with the assurance of knowing I can select the kernel in the way described in his comments.

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
h@h:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[OS Astra Linux 1.11.4 orel - amd64 DVD ]/ orel non-free main contrib  
deb ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/orel/repository/ orel non-free contrib main  
# deb-src ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/orel/repository/ orel non-free contrib main  
# deb ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/1.11/repository/ orel main contrib non-free  
# deb ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/1.11/repository-update/ orel non-free contrib main 
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
# following from stack exchange GAD3R
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `BCM4360` ( info from your question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350137/fresh-linux-mint-18-1-install-no-wireless-though-the-live-cd-it-worked-fine-i))

You don't need to upgrade your kernel version from backports (you have the `4.8` kernel version).

The wifi can be enabled following the steps described on the [debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) page:

Edit your `sources.list` and add `contrib non-free` component :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

Comment: If this breaks my trackpad/mouse, is there a simple way to revert this? I did a dry-run and I guess could just write it all down and uninstall... Right? (I'd rather have a mouse than wifi :)